# Выражение "игра не стоит свеч"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "игра не стоит свеч"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это выражение взято из обихода французских картежников. Означает совсем маленький выигрыш, даже не окупающий стоимость свечей, сгоревших за это время.